# error in dynamic bar chart generation on python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Going by the this example, 
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html

I wanted to generated the dynamic bar chart.so far I have following script.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

groups = int(sys.argv[1])

subgroup = int(sys.argv[2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

index = np.arange(groups)

print index

bar_width = 1.0 / (subgroup + 1)

print bar_width

mainlist = []


for x in range(0, groups):
    #print x
    templist = []
    for num in range(0, subgroup):
        templist.append(num+1)
    #print templist
    mainlist.append(templist)

print mainlist

for cnt in range(0,subgroup):
    plt.bar(index + (bar_width * cnt), mainlist[cnt], bar_width)

plt.savefig('odd_bar_chart.png')
```

This works fine when i pass same values for groups and subgroup,

```
> odd_bar_chart.py 3 3
> odd_bar_chart.py 2 2
```

but if i pass different values like this,

> odd_bar_chart.py 3 2
>   odd_bar_chart.py 2 3

it gives following error
AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length {first argument} or scalar

Now I dont know hw height comes in picture ?
can anybody tell me whats wrong here ?

Comment: The list in `mainlist[cnt]` has the length of `subgroup` while `index` has the length of `group`. You cant plot like that if they have different lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs for `plt.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar). Here the first two arguments are `left` and `height` referring the value of the left hand side of the bar and it's height.

Your error message is informing you that the second argument, `height` should be either the same length as the first or a scalar (single value).

**The error**:
In your iteration at the end you plot the height `mainlist[cnt]` against the left locations `index + (bar_width * cnt)`. Clearly you are trying to adjust the `x` location to spatially separate the bar plots using the `bar_with*cnt` so this is a scalar. The length then of the `left` is given by `index`, which is generated from `index = np.arange(groups)` and so will have length `group`. But the length of the heights is given by `subgroup`, this is done when `templist` (which has length `subgroup`) is appended to `mainlist`.

So your error comes in the way you are generating your data. It is usually better to either stick something in by hand (as they have done in the example you referenced), or use [something form `numpy.random`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html)  to generate a set of random numbers.